# MySQL Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint;

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

i have a task to creat a database about rail-way station.
got an error 1215. i have checked all similar parametres, they all match. however, the program doesn't work.
what is my mistake?
 please help.
this is my model part:

---

```
-- Table `mydb`.`WayOut`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`WayOut` (
  `WayOutNumberr` INT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE INDEX `WayOutNumber_UNIQUE` (`WayOutNumberr` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`WayOutNumberr`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

```
-- Table `mydb`.`TrainOut`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`TrainOut` (
  `NumberTrainOutRec` INT NOT NULL,
  `WayOutNumber` INT NOT NULL,
  `DateOut` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `TrainNumber` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NumberTrainOutRec`, `WayOutNumber`, `TrainNumber`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `WayOutNumber_UNIQUE` (`WayOutNumber` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `WayOutNumber`
    FOREIGN KEY (`WayOutNumber`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`WayOut` (`WayOutNumberr`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

here's a mistake code
what is a decision?(sorry for my english)

```
ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `mydb`.`TrainOut`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`TrainOut` (
          `NumberTrainOutRec` INT NOT NULL,
          `WayOutNumber` INT NOT NULL,
          `DateOut` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
          `TrainNumber` INT NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`NumberTrainOutRec`, `WayOutNumber`, `TrainNumber`),
          UNIQUE INDEX `WayOutNumber_UNIQUE` (`WayOutNumber` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `WayOutNumber`
            FOREIGN KEY (`WayOutNumber`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`WayOut` (`WayOutNumberr`)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
            ON UPDATE CASCADE)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 9 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the database reference from CONSTRAINT. TrainOut is already created in mydb database.

```
REFERENCES `WayOut` (`WayOutNumberr`)
```